# ace:chart : how to change size of chart

Tags: jquery, icefaces-3

I am using icefaces 3.2 ace chart and testing on IE8/firefox. I have a BarChart. I want to know how can i set the height and width of my chart. The problem is if the x axis labels length increases , i notice that the chart height decreases. Just to highlight icefaces charts framework is based on jqplot from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Add in a css:

```
.jqplot-target {
    height: HEIGHT px;  
    width: WIDTH px;
}
```

You can also use the setTickAngle() property to display labels in diagonal

```
xAxis = new Axis();
xAxis.setAutoscale(true);
xAxis.setTickAngle(-30);
```